# How to calculate percentile in R using group by?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe:

```
test <- tibble(
  period = c(
    '2019_q1',
    '2019_q1',
    '2019_q1',
    '2019_q1',
    '2019_q1',
    '2019_q2',
    '2019_q2',
    '2019_q2',
    '2019_q2',
    '2019_q2',
    '2019_q2',
    '2019_q2',
    '2019_q2'
    
  ),
  company = c(
    'google',
    'facebook',
    'amazon',
    'ebay',
    'wikipedia',
    'google',
    'youtube',
    'amazon',
    'wikipedia',
    'yelp',
    'yahoo',
    'tide',
    'target'
  ),
  source = c('website',
             'website',
             'website',
             'website',
             'website',
             'phone',
             'phone',
             'phone',
             'phone',
             'phone',
             'phone',
             'phone',
             'phone'),
  
  values = c(10,
             20,
             30,
             50,
             90,
             6,
             12,
             45,
             52,
             80,
             92,
             8,
             17)
)
```

I would like to calculate the percentiles for this dataframe using the following grouping:

```
group_by(period, source)
```

However whenever i try and do this with the following code i get the error message:

> Error in mutate(): ! Problem while computing percentile =
> quantile(values, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25)). x percentile must be size
> 1, not 5. i The error occurred in group 1: period = "2019_q1",
> source = "website".

When using this code:

```
test %>%    
    group_by(period, source) %>%     
    arrange(period, source) %>%    
    filter(!is.na(values)) %>%    
    mutate(percentile = quantile(values, probs = seq(0,1,0.25)))
```

I'm trying to find out what the percentile is for each of these values by the grouping of period and source.

e.g. for the first grouping the new column would look like this:

| period | company | values | percentile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019_q1 | google | 10 | 25 |
| 2019_q1 | facebook | 20 | 25 |
| 2019_q1 | amazon | 30 | 50 |
| 2019_q1 | ebay | 10 | 50 |
| 2019_q1 | wikipedia | 90 | 75 |

*new update* =  there is grouping by both period and source columns

Comment: You only have one value if you group on period and company right?

Comment: @Quinten yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *find* the percentiles you shouldn't use the `quantile` function but rather its inverse – cumulative distribution function (CDF).

```r
test$percentile <- unlist(tapply(test$values, test$period, function(x) {
  f <- ecdf(x)
  f(x)*100
}))
```

Here I used an empirical distribution function (`ecdf`) but if you have any assumptions on the distribution of the values, you could first fit the correct distribution to the data and then use its parameters in a distributions-specific CDF (`dnorm`, `dbeta`, etc.).

Comment: How does the grouping apply here? As my example groups by two different values

Comment: I understood you are interested in the percentile of each company within each period so grouping is actually done over period only. If I grouped over both period and company, there would be only one observation for each combination (as mentioned above by Quinten) and nothing could be computed from that. Did I understand you correctly, or do you want something else?

Comment: Assume that there are multiple companies for each period, how would it work in that casE?

Comment: That is the case now, do you mean multiple values for one company within a period? What exactly are you trying to compute?

Comment: I will update the table and code now to show you

Comment: the code has been updated to reflect new grouping variable

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't change much as period and source are fully correlated, so there is only website for q1 and only phone for q2.

Comment: Assuming this is the case - can we not calculate percentiles for the individual groupings of both source and period? so the percentiles for phone, - showing which values fall in what percentile for that column etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245949/discussion-between-robert-hacken-and-beans-on-toast).